# What permissions are needed to run Magento?

Tags: magento

The [Magento documentation tells us to do this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh):

```
chmod -R o+w media var
chmod o+w app/etc
```

That gets us past the installer.

Next, I'd like to download a theme from Magento Connect.  Unfortunately, that is throwing an error that seems to be permissions related.

```
Settings has not been loaded. Used default settings
Config file does not exists please save Settings
Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions.
```

What permissions are needed to get past that?

I'm also seeing an error about the connection string.

```
Connection string is empty
```

While we are at it, what are the total set of permissions that must be set to make Magento fully functional (and secure)?

I realize Magento != Wordpress.  It's so close to being as install-friendly as Wordpress.  Just a little more!

Comment: Tons of available info out there on setting Magento permissions. It is not uncommon to set everything to 777 before working with Magento Connect, and then reverting your permissions back to recommended after you've installed what you need to.

Answer (score 17):

I use the following script, and run it every now and then.

In the future, I'm going to add chown -R root.www-pub to the end of it, add all users that have to modify the code to a www-pub group, and set the umask to 0002. In the meantime, the below script works well.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f ./app/etc/local.xml ]; then
    echo "-- ERROR"
    echo "-- This doesn't look like a Magento install.  Please make sure"
    echo "-- that you are running this from the Magento main doc root dir"
    exit
fi

if [ `id -u` != 0 ]; then
    echo "-- ERROR"
    echo "-- This script should be run as root so that file ownership"
    echo "-- changes can be set correctly"
    exit
fi

find . -type f \-exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d \-exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d \-exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./var -type f \-exec chmod 666 {} \;
find ./media -type d \-exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./media -type f \-exec chmod 666 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Comment: Did you ever make the changes you discussed for a new user group?

Answer (score 8):

If you are on a development environment, this is the way to go:

```
chmod -R 777 /magento-directory/
```

Otherwise this should do:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

The first line will find folders and chmod them to 755. The second find files and chmod them to 644.

More from a [Magento wiki article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions).

Comment: Ok. Got it. That doesn't seem entirely secure. Are there any other docs with more granular permissions mentioned?

Comment: The above find and the stuff from Magento are proper permissions for Magento as long as the files are owned by the user that the web server is also running as.  The .htacess that are included in Magento lock out what shouldn't be seen from the webserver.

Comment: @VernBurton, so would it make sense to set `chown ftpuser:www-data public_html -R` and then do the above but with `664` and `775`?

Comment: Yes.  Always ensure that all permission and ownership is to the correct user, it your owner is ftpuser and your group is www-data from the web_root folder and all the magento permission below.  You get issues with Magento Connect(downloader), if your web root isn't owned by your web user.

Comment: It bears repeating: make sure the 'httpdocs' folder also has the correct owner, group and permissions

Answer (score -1):

Below links work well for setting permission in Magento

Here is the permission we need to run for the Magento.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;     
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;     
find ./media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;   
chmod 777 ./app/etc              
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

http://www.letsknowit.com/permissions-needed-to-run-Magento

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -2):

Use The following commands to set permissions, as suggested by the official documentation :

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;

find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 

find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 

find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;

find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 

find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;

chmod 700 includes

chmod 600 includes/config.php
```

I also wrote a complete shell script for automating those tasks :  [mage-set-perms](https://gist.github.com/amineasli/8bde97270d20ffe790f1)

As a bonus the script is also gentle towards security and data integrity tools like tripwire and aide etc.